# Mouse and Keyboard not working on different HDD that I installed

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, keyboard, mouse

Accidentally deleted windows on an hdd, so I replaced the hdd with another one that I had(already had windows). Took a while for it to boot into windows, but when it did I noticed my mouse and keyboard stopped working. For the boot sequence both of them work fine, but once Windows loads in, I can no longer use both the keyboard and mouse. The USB ports also seem to be working fine. I can plug in a hub, and the light turns on. Same with a USB drive. (the light of the usb turns on)If the problem is the firmware how am I supposed to update it without being able to login? Or is there something that I'm missing? If I reload windows on to the hdd will I lose all my data?

I already tried:

- restarting
- trying a different keyboard and mouse

Comment: To make sure I understand your question, please tell me whether this is correct or if I got anything wrong. You have a hard drive where you install Windows in the past on a different computer, and you put that hard drive with Windows on it into a different computer, and things are not working. Also, what research have you done regarding repairing Windows?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. So far, I have just read that I can clean install Windows, and have access to my files. However, it did not say anything about me losing my apps. I just wanna know if there is something that I can do to fix my keyboard and mouse without having to reinstall windows, and the change that I lose my apps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you have replaced your Windows disk with one
that is not working well, and you are worried about your own data
if you reinstall Windows.

I infer from this that your data is on another disk.
In this case, installing Windows on the replaced disk will not harm
any other second disk that is in the computer.
In other words, as long as you don't install Windows on the *same
physical disk that contains your data*, the data is safe.

The question is : Why in this case not return the previous disk to its
rightful computer?

I also think that your first action when you get Windows working
should be to take a backup of your data. You could even, for safety,
use a Linux Live USB for taking backups before installing Windows.

Comment: On the disk that I removed, I accidentally deleted Windows, so it is empty. The second one's original place was a slow environment, that's why I put it in another pc. Now that I have replaced it, the keyboard and mouse don't work.

Comment: I understood that - please read my answer. If you need help, ask a more knowledgeable person for help. You should be careful, since if your data is not backed up and you execute these operations without a total understanding of them, you risk losing your data.

Answer (score 0):

"I replaced the hdd with another one that I had(already had windows)." Likely the HDD was **not** one that had previously been installed in that PC.

When Windows (or other operating systems, such as Linux) are being installed on a PC, [*drivers specific for that machine*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-the-driver-selection-process) are selected and installed. Many drivers for an Acer Aspire 3 laptop would not work in the  MSI Codex R Gaming Desktop and *vice versa*.

The best way to make sure your data is safe and reinstall Windows is:

- Make a full disk image of the drive on other media, e.g., external HDD, using a bootable rescue USB, such as the [Macrium Rescue Environment](https://www.macrium.com/blog/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/aomei-data-backuper/). *Verify* the image.
- Download the Windows ISO from Microsoft and make a USB using their media creation tool.
- Try reinstalling Windows, keeping files. If that works, the data should be OK on the HDD.
- If it fails, you might have to reinstall Windows *completely*, destroying data -- but that can then be restored from the disk image.